# getting back duplicate data from ashx file upload

Tags: javascript, .net, upload, ashx

I'm using a post command to upload a file from a JavaScript function.  I need to pass additional parameter along with uploading the file:

```
         function handleFileSelect(evt) {
         var memberID = '12222';
         var input = document.getElementById('input-file').files[0];
         var formData = new FormData();
         formData.append('file[]', input);
         formData.append('memberid', memberID);     
         $.ajax({
             url: 'FileUploadHandler.ashx',
             type: "POST",
             data: formData,
             processData: false,
             contentType: false,
             success: function (data) {
```

When I ask for the memberID to be returned (for testing) it comes back with 12222,2514.  The 2514 is a variable set for memberID so duplicate data is coming back.  I added another parm this time the username and it is added twice with a comma separating the two.  Like bob,bob

ashx code:

```
          Public Class FileUploadHandler Implements System.Web.IHttpHandler

Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
              If context.Request.Files.Count > 0 Then
            Dim pathrefer As String = context.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()
            Dim Serverpath As String = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Upload_Bio_Files")

            Dim postedFile = context.Request.Files(0)
            Dim memberID As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params("memberid")
            context.Response.Write(memberID)
```

I've changed some of the code in the ashx page to split the parameter and take the first value but I feel that is only a workaround and there should be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution;

If I set the parameters to something other than my variable names it works fine.  I set them to param1 and param2 and it does not duplicate the values,

```
         var memberID = '12222';
         var username = 'Robert';
         var input = document.getElementById('input-file').files[0];
         var formData = new FormData();
         formData.append('file[]', input);
         formData.append('param1', memberID);     
         formData.append('param2', username);
```

and on the ashx side:

```
          Dim param1 = context.Request.Params("param1")
          Dim param2 As String = context.Request.Params("param2")
```